# Excel VBA- Modify code so data transferred from 'Invoice' sheet to 'Sales Book' sheet save to a different workbook instead

Tags: vba, excel

*I have this code, which sends data from the 'Invoice' sheet to 'Sales Book' sheet, but after consideration feel it would be beneficial to have the data sent to a different workbook altogether. How would I implement this using the code below (as it took me ages to get this far!!). Here is the code-* This was the original question. It is now completely solved and Updated below-

The code below now works. The last issue to resolve is the fact that the data copied over also copies over empty item rows. I found a simple solution to this which I will copy the code below the pic here. It's basically an auto run vba code that deletes a row if there is no data in a certain cell. Thanks for the help. I feel invincible!

```
Sub sendtosales()
Dim WB As Workbook  '''!
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook  '''!
Dim WBLoc As String  '''!
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim rng_dest As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WBLoc = "C:\Salestracker.xlsm"  '''! Location of the workbook, trimmed down for public view
Set CurrentWB = Excel.ThisWorkbook  '''!
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(WBLoc)   '''! Opens the workbook
i = 1
Set rng_dest = WB.Sheets("Salestracker").Range("D:F") '''! Change Sheets() to whichever sheet you want to use

' Find first empty row in columns D:F on sheet Sales Book
Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
   i = i + 1
Loop

'Copy range A23:D27 on sheet Invoice to Variant array
Set rng = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("A23:D27") '''!

' Copy rows containing values to sheet Sales Book
For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
  rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
  With WB.Sheets("Salestracker")  '''! Change Sheets() to whichever sheet you want to use
     'Copy Invoice number
     .Range("B" & i).Value = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("C18").Value '''!
     'Copy Date
     .Range("A" & i).Value = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("C15").Value '''!
     'Copy Company name
     .Range("C" & i).Value = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("A7").Value '''!
  End With  '''!
  i = i + 1
End If
Next a

WB.Close savechanges:=True  '''! This wil close the Workbook and save changes

Set WB = Nothing  '''! Cleaning memory
Set CurrentWB = Nothing  '''! Cleaning memory
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image: Image of Invoice and Salestracker with comments in red, and the problem bit on saletracker are greyed-out]

Here is the code that deletes rows that have no data in a certain cell, F in my case-

```
Sub killemptyF()
On Error Resume Next
Columns("F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

and here is the code to auto run this module whenever the workbook is opened-

```
Sub Auto_Run()
Run ("killemptyF")
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want it to create a new workbook or do you already have a workbook you want the data to be copied to?

Comment: Avoid loop, use `nmbRowsD = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales Book").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1` to find first empty row in column D (might be wrong, you might need both D and F to be empty, if so, use function **MAX** with nmbRowsD and nbmRowsF). If you already have a workbook, make sure to open it first and refer to ranges in it as Workbook("WorkbookName").Worksheet("SheetName").Range()

Comment: @slaqr I have one created already. I want the data that is being sent to 'Sales Book' sheet, to be sent to the 'Salestracker' workbook (1st sheet called salestracker in that book). The sales book and the salestracker are identical, just in different books

Comment: @AntiDrondert Out of interest, why avoid loop? I am having a problem where the data is copied over to the new book (thanks to Slaqrs code below), but it copies all 5 entries, even though only 1 has been used. It copies over the date and invoice number, and leaves the rest blank. When a new invoice is created, it overwrites these lines with the new data. Do you think that is because I am using loop?

Comment: `Set rng = Sheets("Invoice").Range("A23:D27") ` this line defines number of rows you want to copy further in code, if that is what you ask. Overwriting the data could result because of incorrect calculation of rows, yes. If you add couple of screenshots of what you had at the begining/result of macros/what you wanted I could help when I get home.

Comment: Fixed it by adding a simple vba code to the salestraker book. Will update all accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Everything I've added/edited i've marked with `'''!`.

```
Sub sendtosales()
Dim WB as Workbook  '''!
Dim CurrentWB as Workbook  '''!
Dim WBLoc as String  '''!
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long
Dim rng_dest As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WBLoc = "C:\Documents\Salestracker.xlsm"  '''! Location of the workbook
Set CurrentWB = Excel.ThisWorkbook  '''!
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(WBLoc)   '''! Opens the workbook
i = 1
Set rng_dest = WB.Sheets(1).Range("D:F") '''! Change Sheets() to whichever sheet you want to use

' Find first empty row in columns D:F on sheet Sales Book
Do Until WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng_dest.Rows(i)) = 0
   i = i + 1
Loop

'Copy range A23:D27 on sheet Invoice to Variant array
Set rng = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("A23:D27") '''!

' Copy rows containing values to sheet Sales Book
For a = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(a)) <> 0 Then
  rng_dest.Rows(i).Value = rng.Rows(a).Value
  With WB.Sheets(1)  '''! Change Sheets() to whichever sheet you want to use
     'Copy Invoice number
     .Range("B" & i).Value = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("C18").Value '''!
     'Copy Date
     .Range("A" & i).Value = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("C15").Value '''!
     'Copy Company name
     .Range("C" & i).Value = CurrentWB.Sheets("Invoice").Range("A7").Value '''!
  End With  '''!
  i = i + 1
End If
Next a

WB.Close savechanges:=True  '''! This wil close the Workbook and save changes

Set WB = Nothing  '''! Cleaning memory
Set CurrentWB = Nothing  '''! Cleaning memory
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit: Added declaration of current workbook to avoid confusion of which workbook to use.